# Any good papers on Fixed Income Option pricing?

Tags: options, option-pricing, fixed-income, callable-bonds, bond-options

Whilst I have managed to find plenty of material on pricing of Interest Rate Options (i.e. Caps, Floors, Swaptions, spread-options, etc.), I haven't really managed to find any solid papers on the topic of "pricing models for options on Fixed Income": i.e. Treasury & Bund Options and / or options embedded in callable & putable corporate or government bonds.

I've googled and haven't really been able to find any good PDFs on SSRN or other resource websites or journals (I know there's the book by Vladimir Piterbarg, specifically volume III, that might cover some aspects of the Bond option pricing theory, but at this point in time, I am just looking for freely available papers that have been accepted as the "industry standard" on the topic).

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Ps: I am not looking for lecture notes on how to price bonds using the Vasicek model or the Hull-White model :) My assumption is that the industry has moved on and the standard nowadays is different (I just haven't managed to find any such papers).

Comment: I don't know of anything close to an industry standard.

The shop where we both used to work has a nice inernal paper on bond options, with a focus on high-yield bonds. It uses a 2-dimensional tree, one dimension for rates, another for credit. It also discusses a lot the various ways of predicting the forward price of the undelrying bond, none of which are perfect.

Comment: @DimitriVulis: thank you so much!

Comment: Would you guys be able to pass on a reference?

Comment: sorry!! I'd love to but, but I don't think we're allowed. I passed on to Jan the name of the guy who wrote the paper and might help him. A lot more people tried to make markets in bond options in the 1990s - until 2005 I'd say. There used to be a lot more activity than now, especially in option of Brady bonds (emerging markets bonds partially guaranteed by U.S. government) and high-yield bonds. The strike was almost always clean price, but I've seen yield and even dirty price. This market has almost disappeared.

Comment: Last I knew, over a decade ago, simple OTC fixed income options tended to be priced on variants of the Libor Market Model, or when possible using something like SABR.  I think curve treatment has improved considerably though, with less presumed equivalence between swap rates and treasury rates, etc.  Embedded options _still_ tended to be priced by astonishingly simplistic models.

Comment: @BrianB: when you say "I think curve treatment has improved considerably though, with less presumed equivalence between swap rates and treasury rates", what do you mean exactly? I.e. nowadays, swaptions would normally be priced via the Libor Market Model, where the forward Swap rate follows a rather complicated process (sum of forward libors, with stochastic discount factors). I take it that a different model would be used to model (say) the forward 10y Treasury yields? (and that would make sense because it's different to 10y forward swap rates). But what model would be used for the T-yields?

Comment: The LMM is basically a standardized Heath-Jarrow-Morton approach, and so a HJM variant would be used for the treasury based market too.  Of course, when rates can go negative as particularly in Japan, you have to watch how you construct the model.

Answer (score 2):

In the area that I'm familiar with, options on MBS TBAs, as commented by Dimitri, there don't appear to be any standard models. Among other reasons, this is probably due to a lack of liquidity in the sector (there are very few market makers) and the fact that any such mortgage option model will show some dependence on the prepayment model/OAS pricing framework, which themselves lack standardization. For a flavor of some of the modeling considerations involved in pricing mortgage options, take a look at [Mortgage Options: A Primer](http://docshare01.docshare.tips/files/13953/139535002.pdf).